# How do I build an app with a completed Python code for it?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, windows

So I've made a Python code for a simple app, and I want to build an app around it with a proper user interface (either an android app or a PC app is fine), doesn't need to be complicated, just so that it could be more than just lines in the command prompt. Where should I start, and which other language should I start learning if necessary?
Thank you.

Comment: This is a question which I have always wanted answered, and I am sure many others do too. unfortunately, I sense it will be downvoted and closed because people on Stack Overflow don't like this kind of question.

Comment: You seem to be referring to a Graphical User Interface(GUI). tkinter is the standard library to use in python. Python using 3rd party libraries like Flask or Django could also be used to design a web interface. pyqt is an interface to QT and TCL which is another GUI library.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tkinter` or `PyQt` to create a GUI for PC in python.

`tkinter` is simpler to use while `pyqt` offers more features right out of the box

for a mobile compatible `gui` you could use `kivy` also in python.